# BigQuery and Looker Studio - Extracting the value of @DS_USER_EMAIL in a query

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

So in the BigQuery console you can see the queries that have been run by your users. Looker Studio supplies a parameter called `@DS_USER_EMAIL` that contains the email of the user that made the query.

We need that email for billing reasons: We need to bill/notify people based on their usage.

An example query of this, logged in BQ:

```
select @DS_USER_EMAIL as user_email from test_table;
```

So I can only see the variable, not the resolved value. Was hoping the logged query would be actual query run like so:

```
select 'test@test.com' as user_email from test_table;
```

Any way around this? If not, what are our options for getting the email?

Comment: I am not able to understand this use case. How do you pass this parameter from DS to BQ? What should be result of presented statements?

Comment: You create a DS connector to BQ. In that connector, you can use @DS_USER_EMAIL as a variable, which is grabbed from the user that is using DS. Does that make it clearer? If not, let me know, and I'll try to explain it better above.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, `@DS_USER_EMAIL` can be used to create dynamic reports, so certain users get access to specific data ([Ref](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10588439))

If you are looking for a way to check total bytes processed based on the user e-mail you can try using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables and `JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION` ([Documentation Link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs#schema))

An example:

```
SELECT
 job_id,
 creation_time,
 user_email, 
 total_bytes_billed
FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION
WHERE state == "DONE"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I keep getting an error that the table is not found when doing the select: `SELECT * FROM region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA. JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION;` If I change the region to `region-us` the error goes away, but all our data is in the EU.

Comment: there's a space before ```JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION``` in the code you shared, maybe that? if not, can you please share the full error message?

Comment: This is weird. Running the statement `SELECT creation_time, user_email, job_id, query FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION
order by creation_time desc
limit 5;` results in `Not found: Table tillty-pos:region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION`, while running your statement: `Access Denied: Table tillty-pos:region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION: User does not have permission to query table tillty-pos:region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION.`. My Roles: roles/billing.projectManager, roles/datastore.owner, roles/owner

Comment: I've reported the issue on their issue tracker. I sadly cannot verify if your answer works.

Comment: That's weird. I've been reading more about this issue, and would suggest you try using the specific region qualifier of your project, instead of the eu/us multi locations. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro#region_qualifier. And no problem, if you figure out what's going on, i'd like to know :)

Comment: I've tried various regions, none of them work. I'm as confused as you are. ‍♂️

Comment: I never did solve the permission issue while querying `JOBS_BY_ORGANIZATION`, but I think `JOBS_BY_PROJECT` will suffice. However your query above doesn't solve my issue, as `user_email` only shows the owner of the data source, which is a general user we've created. I need it to show who is logged into data studio. :-)